# Arabic text defaulting to default font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, arabic, typography

I have converted some open source ttfs from freearabicfonts.com into webfonts using fontsquirrel's webfont converter and gone through the usual css3 steps to get a webfont working (it's definitely there). However, when I try to use the font on arabic text it doesn't work.

background check:

db tables set to utf8, text saved in db as valid arabic, defaultcharset in htaccess set to utf-8, mysql connection: set names as utf-8 done, html5 meta tag set to utf-8, in view source the text is arabic, on the page, the text is arabic..... but the font is the ugly browser standard one...

Anyone ever seen this... I'm pulling my hair out...

Thanks very much indeed.
A

Comment: We definitely need to see your site. All I can say is that it's _probably_ not a UTF-8 problem.

Comment: it's all on localhost right now and it's pretty huge to deploy mate. the other annoying thing is that jsfiddle won't allow a cross browser webfont inclusion without permission errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a LOT of reading, and bear in mind I am not an Arabic speaker/writer, here are my discoveries and solutions so far:

Currently, there are no solid ways of making Arabic webfonts via online font converters however I would imagine that this will change moving forward.

The options for arabic fonts are the following:

(1) You can use webfonts.fonts.com and their arabic fonts, this list is growing fairly quickly and as of writing this there are 35 font families (195 fonts) link here:
http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/Project/Choosefonts#languages%3DW20%26page%3D1

(2) If you *have* to use your font then you have to convert it yourself and beware, there be dragons down there... The way I font was to use [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) which is available for unix, for mac you should get this via macports using `sudo port install fontforge` in the terminal. I think you can get it running in windows using cygwin too. You have to do a lot in the advanced export options to get a perfect result. There's simply too much to explain everything on this post. Instead I strongly recommend you skim read this to get a better grasp of output options from fontforge:
http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/overview.html

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/gposgsub.html

it's all down to ligatures, glyphs & subsets, however I'm not sure i got mine right as I don't write arabic but mine seems to finally visually match things ok.

(3) As of writing this Google's free arabic webfonts are finished however look over here to track progress:
http://shashafont.com/

I'd really strongly recommend option 1.
Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

The font squirrell converter by default generates a fairly minimal font to keep the size small; any non-Latin characters are removed.

You have to enable some of the advanced options to maintain the arabic glyphs in the font: under "subsetting" choose "custom" or "no subsetting". I haven't actually tried it myself though.

Comment: yep, I've just run a test, sadly no dice either